# Tabular table wordbreak

Tags: tabularx

I've got the following table (generated by pandoc html => tex):

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Naam
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
Eigenschap
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Value
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
TesttesttesttestTesttesttesttest
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
String lal ei igigieieieieieie
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lalalaallala
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Test test test test
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
String
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lalalaallala
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Test test test test
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
String
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lalalaallala
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Test test test test
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
String
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lalalaallala
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Test test test test
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.46\columnwidth}\raggedright
String
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lalalaallala
\end{minipage}
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

The second row and the first cell has the value 'Testtesttestst....', the 'word' should be broken; otherwise you'll see the table like this:
[image: wrong table]

I know this is fixable with \hline - but that doesn't seem to do the job for me..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\centering%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Naam & Eigenschap & Value\\
\hline
TesttesttesttestTesttesttesttest
&
String lal ei igigieieieieieie
&
Lalalaallala
\\
Test test test test
&
String
&
Lalalaallala
\\
Test test test test
&
String
&
Lalalaallala
\\
Test test test test
&
String
&
Lalalaallala\\
&
String
&
Lalalaallala
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No the markup should preferably be the same.. Adding \hline

Comment: Is there also a way to automate this?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure whether from html.  The other way around is easier since latex is much richer than html.